# How to access azure scheduler with azure ad application access token

Tags: azure

I followed the following guide:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-arm-deployment/

to setup azure ad application.

but it do not seem to work with the azure scheduler.
var cred = new TokenCloudCredentials(_options.SubscriptionId, _options.Token);

```
using (var schedulerServiceClient = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler.CloudServiceManagementClient(cred))
{
    var services = await schedulerServiceClient.CloudServices.ListAsync(token);
}
```

the error and output can be see below. my question is, do an azure ad application not work against all azure services?

I tried a few things like using a azure token on behalf of myself instead of the azure application and then it works just fine.

```
Test Name:  TestMethod1
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result Message: 
Test method Ascend.Scheduler.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
Hyak.Common.CloudException: ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
Result StandardOutput:  
Debug Trace:
te.processhost.managed.exe Information: 0 : 12/6/2015 9:36:25 PM:  - AuthenticationContext: ADAL .NET with assembly version '2.19.0.0', file version '2.19.20802.0213' and informational version 'f719a3fb5ab2559980bb7e75ee78bc15068282fa' is running...
te.processhost.managed.exe Information: 0 : 12/6/2015 9:36:25 PM: e9d31ff5-f1ed-4bf6-b1d7-a180841409d6 - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition started:
    Authority: https://login.windows.net/ascend.xyz/
    Resource: https://management.core.windows.net/
    ClientId: 5519b0a9-aeef-4ff8-b41b-2598a6888687
    CacheType: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.TokenCache (0 items)
    Authentication Target: Client

te.processhost.managed.exe Information: 0 : 12/6/2015 9:36:25 PM: e9d31ff5-f1ed-4bf6-b1d7-a180841409d6 - TokenCache: Looking up cache for a token...
te.processhost.managed.exe Information: 0 : 12/6/2015 9:36:25 PM: e9d31ff5-f1ed-4bf6-b1d7-a180841409d6 - TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache
te.processhost.managed.exe Information: 0 : 12/6/2015 9:36:26 PM: e9d31ff5-f1ed-4bf6-b1d7-a180841409d6 - TokenCache: Storing token in the cache...
te.processhost.managed.exe Information: 0 : 12/6/2015 9:36:26 PM: e9d31ff5-f1ed-4bf6-b1d7-a180841409d6 - TokenCache: An item was stored in the cache
te.processhost.managed.exe Information: 0 : 12/6/2015 9:36:26 PM: e9d31ff5-f1ed-4bf6-b1d7-a180841409d6 - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: JMsx9YOCod0W2iHyyRwr6n3FBo8qp/X/iGNGmZxlvbw=
    Refresh Token Hash: [No Refresh Token]
    Expiration Time: 12/6/2015 10:36:25 PM +00:00
    User Hash: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Scheduler supports both the Service Management and Resource Management endpoints.  The Service Management endpoint (https://management.core.windows.net/) uses certificates and the Resource Management (https://management.azure.com/) endpoint use OAuth.
You can use the Azure Resource Manager Scheduler SDK (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Scheduler) that authenticates using OAuth to manage your Scheduler jobs.

Regards,
Kevin Lam

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.  I don't think this is available with ARM APi yet...

Comment: So is it only services that can be provided with ARM api that can be deployed using a azure ad application?